# Get list of logged in users

Tags: ruby, linux

How do I get a list of logged-in users in Linux with Ruby, without having to process the output of `w` or `who`?

If the only way is with a Rubygem, that is OK, but if there is a way to do it without installing anything AND without using any external programs that would be really nice.

Comment: Does Ruby wrap the `utmpx` api?

Comment: @Duck It does for Solaris (with a gem): https://rubygems.org/gems/solaris-utmpx

Comment: @Duck, https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/193043

Comment: Hmmm seems like maybe I will have to create a Rubygem...

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged to your question 'Linux', I would go to something like:

```
who | cut -f2 -d " "
console
ttys000
```

Or within `irb`:

```
$ irb
1.9.3p194 :001 > exec 'who | cut -f2 -d " "'
console
ttys000
```

see also: [Other options to run a shell command](http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html).

Here is how to get the current user with non-os dependent way using [Etc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/etc/rdoc/Etc.html):

```
$ irb
1.9.3p194 :001 > require 'etc'
 => true 
1.9.3p194 :002 > Etc.getlogin
 => "DudeRoot"
```

---

One more option is to [compile a `.c` extension code](http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to-create-a-ruby-extension-in-c-in-under-5-minutes-100.html) which does whatever you need and publish it for other people on github.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to do it WITHOUT using an external program.

Comment: You can interact with the OS without using 'w' or 'who' in most languages. But can you do it /easily/ in Ruby?

Comment: Still not what I want. I know about Etc.getlogin. But it only gets "my" username. I want to get an array of logged-in users. I have a Linux computer that my friends log in to.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Rubygem with a native extension that wraps the `utmp` API: [rutmp](https://github.com/fugalh/rutmp)

You can use it to keep calling `getutent` to collect information about all logged in users.

I do not see how this is simpler than parsing the output of `w`, which is guaranteed to exist on every Linux system.

Why do you want to avoid calling an external program at any cost?

Comment: Why do I want to avoid calling an external program? Speed. And, IIRC, programmers are not recommended to rely on the output of external programs. I have tried `rutmp`. IIRC it didn't compile.

Comment: How often will your program shell out to `w`, in practice?  Here's what I get from invoking `time who`: `who  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.003 total`.  That's even below the measurement threshold.  Probably there is not going to be a discernable difference between parsing `w` and going through a Rubygem.  Who told you that you're not recommended to go through an external program?  That's only true if your Ruby program is running with root privileges (do not use `system()` or backtick invocation in that case for security reasons).  The power of Unix comes from chaining programs together.

Comment: Oh, and I have tried `rutmp`, too, before recommending it here.  Compiled without a hitch on my machine.

Comment: Interesting...I got several pages of syntax errors...What did you compile it on?

Comment: BTW `w` takes 0.01 seconds on my computer (it is really old).

Comment: I'm running Debian wheezy/jessie on amd64.  Ruby 1.8.7, though - maybe *rutmp* is not compatible with 1.9.x.  If speed is such a concern here, you should not be writing a Ruby program.

Comment: Perhaps the Ruby version is the issue. I think I might just continue to use `w`. It was just that if there WAS a builtin Ruby way of doing it, I wanted to use it.

Comment: There definitely is none.